# Why do android run methods like "onItemSelected" even if they are not called in the oncreate Method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello everyone i begin to learn Android development and i do not Unterstand how it works.
I understood that there is not a main. Instead it is the android lifecyle. But now i do not Unterstand why methods like "onItemSelected" or "onTouchEvent" executes by android even if tbis  methods do not called.

Answer (score 1):

Tahir!

These methods are listeners, so they are listening to the special action you make. They will be called every time you select the item or touch a UI stuff you are listening to. For example, there is a method called `setOnClickListener` which listens every time you click on something, e.g. any button you have. The syntaxis will be like:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_cool_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your handler code here
    }
});
```

It will be called on touch your button no matter where it is.